# Propogate errors to UI with Spring 3 MVC / REST

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, error-handling, ftp

When /api/upload REST endpoint is accessed I have a UploadController that uses a service UploadService to upload a file to an ftp server with org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient. I would like to be able to send information back to the user if the ftp client was unable to connect or timed out, or successfully sent the file. I have some IOException handling, but I don't know how to turn that around and send it back to the front-end. Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
public void upload(InputStream inputStream) {
    String filename = "file.txt"

    client = new FTPClient();
    try {
        client.connect("ftpsite");
        client.login("username", "password");
        client.storeFile(filename, inputStream);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {

            if (inputStream!= null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should throw a new Exception in your catch statement.

For example, you could create a RequestTimeoutException class:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
public class RequestTimeoutException extends RuntimeException { }
```

and then throw it when need be:

```
catch (IOException ioe) {

    //do some logging while you're at it
    throw new RequestTimeoutException();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a simple solution to exactly what I need.